# Using to_json gives me illegal character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, syntax-error, illegal-characters, to-json

I passed a ruby variable to javascript using the to_json method, but the console returns me an error saying "SyntaxError: illegal character" for the following line:

```
var home = #{@home.to_json};
```

Does anyone knows whats wrong?

Comment: Is it in a `.slim` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in a `.erb` file you can do the following:

```
var home = <%= @home.to_json %>;
```

Otherwise (haml or something else) you could use the `parseJSON` method from `jQuery` in combination with Ruby's string interpolation:

```
var home = $.parseJSON("#{@home.to_json}");
```

More information about the `parseJSON` method can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, I was using based on haml. But now I have a SyntaxError: invalid property id, on the same line, for some reason it converts the line like this:
`{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Minas Gerais&quot;, [etc.] `
And when I set the variable directly with javascript, it works: 
`{"name": "Minas Gerais", [etc.] `

Comment: You could try to use `html_safe`, so `@home.to_json.html_safe`. You might not even need to use `parseJSON` when using that. I'll update my answer if that works for you.